# Euclidean distance using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance of two binary data (image) using numpy but I am getting `nan` in the result

```
def eculideanDistance(features, predict, dist):
    dist += (float(features[0]) - float(predict[0]))
    return math.sqrt(dist)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hsUz.png)

I am using this binary data

```
train_set = {
    0: [
        ["0000000000000111100000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000001111111011111100000000000000000111111100000111100000000000000001111111000000011100000000000000011111110000000111100000000000000111111100000000111000000000000001111111000000001110000000000000011111100000000011110000000000000111111000000000011100000000000001111110000000000111000000000000001111110000000000111000000000000011111100000000001110000000000000111111000000000011100000000000001111110000000000111000000000000111111100000000011110000000000001111011000000000111100000000000011110000000000011110000000000000011110000000000011110000000000000111100000000001111100000000000001111000000000111110000000000000011110000000011111000000000000000011100000011111100000000000000000111100011111110000000000000000001111111111111100000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000011111000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000"],
        ["0000000000011111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000111111101111111000000000000000001111110001111111000000000000000011111100001111110000000000000001111111000001111110000000000000011111110000001111100000000000000011111100000001111110000000000001111111000000001111110000000000011111100000000001111100000000000111111000000000011111100000000001111110000000000111111000000000011111100000000000111110000000000111111000000000001111100000000001111110000000000011111000000000011111100000000000111110000000000111111000000000001111100000000000111110000000000011111000000000001111110000000001111110000000000011111100000000111111000000000000011111100000001111111000000000000011111000000111111100000000000000111110000011111110000000000000001111110001111111000000000000000011111111111111100000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111110000000000000"]
    ],
    1: [
        ["0000000000000000111100000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000111111111110000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000111111111111111100000000000000011111111111111110000000000000001111111111111111100000000000000011111111111111111000000000000000001111111111111110000000000000000011111110111111100000000000000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111100000000"],
        ["0000000001111100000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111000000000011111111111111111111110000000000001111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111"],
    ]
}

test_set = ["0000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000001111111111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000111111111111111100000000000000001111111111111111000000000000000001111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000010000111111111100000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111000000000"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not binary data. This is a binary image stored as a string, where the pixels are either represented by `0` (black) or `1` (white).

To make things easier, lets convert your data to 32 x 32 `numpy array` and visualize it.

#### Converting `train_set` to `numpy array`

```
train_img = {label: [np.uint8([*sample[0]]).reshape(32, 32) 
    for sample in samples] 
        for label, samples in train_set.items()}
```

[image]

#### Converting `test_set` to `numpy array`

```
test_img = np.uint8([*test_set[0]]).reshape(32, 32)
```

[image]

From this point, calculating the euclidean distance using `numpy` is pretty straightforward using [`numpy.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html). e.g.:

```
In [5]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[0][0])

Out[5]: 2984.7336564591487


In [6]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[0][1])

Out[6]: 3459.016189612301


In [7]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[1][0])

Out[7]: 1691.5064291926294


In [8]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[1][1])

Out[8]: 2650.0669802855928
```

#### Full code for this answer

```
In [1]: import numpy as np


In [2]: train_set = {

   ...:     0: [

   ...:         ["0000000000000111100000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000001111111011111100000000000000000111111100000111100000000000000001111111000000011100000000000000011111110000000111100000000000000111111100000000111000000000000001111111000000001110000000000000011111100000000011110000000000000111111000000000011100000000000001111110000000000111000000000000001111110000000000111000000000000011111100000000001110000000000000111111000000000011100000000000001111110000000000111000000000000111111100000000011110000000000001111011000000000111100000000000011110000000000011110000000000000011110000000000011110000000000000111100000000001111100000000000001111000000000111110000000000000011110000000011111000000000000000011100000011111100000000000000000111100011111110000000000000000001111111111111100000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000011111000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000"],

   ...:         ["0000000000011111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000111111101111111000000000000000001111110001111111000000000000000011111100001111110000000000000001111111000001111110000000000000011111110000001111100000000000000011111100000001111110000000000001111111000000001111110000000000011111100000000001111100000000000111111000000000011111100000000001111110000000000111111000000000011111100000000000111110000000000111111000000000001111100000000001111110000000000011111000000000011111100000000000111110000000000111111000000000001111100000000000111110000000000011111000000000001111110000000001111110000000000011111100000000111111000000000000011111100000001111111000000000000011111000000111111100000000000000111110000011111110000000000000001111110001111111000000000000000011111111111111100000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000000111111111111000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111110000000000000"]

   ...:     ],

   ...:     1: [

   ...:         ["0000000000000000111100000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111100000000000000000000111111111110000000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000111111111111111100000000000000011111111111111110000000000000001111111111111111100000000000000011111111111111111000000000000000001111111111111110000000000000000011111110111111100000000000000000011110001111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111100000000"],

   ...:         ["0000000001111100000000000000000000000000001111100000000000000000000000000011111100000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000000111111100000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000000000001111111000000000000000000001111111111111111111000000000000111111111111111111111000000000001111111111111111111111000000000011111111111111111111110000000000001111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111"],

   ...:     ]

   ...: }

   ...: 

   ...: test_set = ["0000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000011111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000000011111111111000000000000000000001111111111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000011111111111110000000000000000000111111111111100000000000000000001111111111111000000000000000000111111111111110000000000000000111111111111111100000000000000001111111111111111000000000000000001111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000111111111111111111100000000000001111111111111111111000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000010000111111111100000000000000000000001111111110000000000000000000000011111111100000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000000111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000001111111111000000000000000000000011111111110000000000000000000011111111111100000000000000000000000111111111100000000000000000000000111111000000000"]

   ...: 


In [3]: train_img = {label: [np.uint8([*sample[0]]).reshape(32, 32) 

   ...:     for sample in samples] 

   ...:         for label, samples in train_set.items()}


In [4]: test_img = np.uint8([*test_set[0]]).reshape(32, 32)


In [5]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[0][0])

Out[5]: 2984.7336564591487


In [6]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[0][1])

Out[6]: 3459.016189612301


In [7]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[1][0])

Out[7]: 1691.5064291926294


In [8]: np.linalg.norm(test_img - train_img[1][1])

Out[8]: 2650.0669802855928
```

Comment: thanks for the answer its really helpful just one small confusion I am not getting the ```np.uint8([*sample[0]])``` this part

Comment: @mbnhmd `sample[0]` gets the first element of the list, which is a string of `0`s and `1`s (e.g. `"001110011....00110"`). `[*sample[0]]` converts a string to list (Refer to [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) for more information). Finally, `np.uint8([*sample[0]])` converts a list to numpy array.

Comment: I am using python 2.7 that's why I wasn't able to crack that one :)

Comment: @mbnhmd For python 2.7 you can use `np.uint8(list(sample[0]))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you use for Euclidean distance is not correct. You will end up computing square root of negative numbers and this is why you get `NaN`. I think you meant doing something like:

```
def euclideanDistance(features, predict, dist):
    diff = (float(features[0]) - float(predict[0]))
    dist += diff * diff 
    return math.sqrt(dist)
```

(I'm not sure why you always use index `0` and why the `dist` variable is a parameter and not only a return value. I suspect there might be a problem with this also but I lack context to judge.)

However, if you instead encode your images as Numpy arrays instead of strings, Numpy offers a direct way to compute Euclidean norm if you encode :

```
a = numpy.array([0,0,1,1])
b = numpy.array([1,0,0,1])
euclidean_norm = numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)
```

Comment: thank for the answer but its still giving the same "nan" even with your formula and with the Euclidean norm it gives an error like "AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'sqrt'"

Comment: @mbnhmd Can you add to your description how you call the `euclideanDistance` function? The error might be there.

Comment: I am sure there is no error in function calling part thanks though :)